# Edge impulse is not providing arduino accerlerometer continious code on build

Tags: arduino, rp2040

I am working on Arduino Nano RP2040. Since Edge impulse doesn’'t specifically provide model library for Nano RP2040, I get the model libraries in Nano BLE and with some teaks I deploy them on Nano RP2040 which was working fine.

I am working on the models related to accelerometer data. Initially, whenever I got the model by edge impulse, it had nano_ble_accelerometer_continuous file. And with some tweaks it was working on Arduino RP2040. But today, when I was working on the new model, this new model library did,'t contain the nano_ble_accelerometer_continuous but only nano_ble_accelerometer.

I thought I had some problems in my trained data. Hence, I went to the model which I created in the start of month for which I got nano_ble_accelerometer_continuous file back before then. But when I run it now, I again got nano_ble_accelerometer for that model too.

Am I am going wrong anywhere or there is some major update? I need to have a accelerometer_continous code.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but this was resolved a few weeks back, and the continuous sketch is now included again.